# How to only select one item from a number of JLists in Swing

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist

So i have a GUI which creates Jlists when categories are created. I only want the user to be able to select one item from any jlist at a time. I also am retrieving information about that item selected, its position in a linked list for example. However with my code so far i get an error, but it doesn't seem to affect functionality, was wondering if anyone could help me work how why or how to fix it?

This is my code:

```
public void addListener(final JList jList, final int curListCount) {
        jList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                jLabel2.setText("");
                if (isSelected == true) {
                    isSelected = false;
                    jList.clearSelection();
                    jLabel2.setText("");
                }
                String selectedString = (jList.getSelectedValue().toString());
                jLabel2.setText(selectedString);
                int selectedIndex = jList.getSelectedIndex();
                isSelected = true;
                System.out.println("Array position is: " + curListCount);
                System.out.println("LinkedList position is: " + selectedIndex);
             }
        });
}
```

And the error that comes up is:

```
'Array position is: 3 LinkedList position is: 0 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at smartChart.wbt$1.valueChanged(wbt.java:57)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1798)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1812)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:405)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:415)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:576)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:420)
at javax.swing.JList.clearSelection(JList.java:2045)
at smartChart.wbt$1.valueChanged(wbt.java:54)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1798)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1812)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:154)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:685)
at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(JList.java:2142)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicListUI.java:2796)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)'
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should always point out the line that the exception is pointing to. What line is 57?

Comment: Ah, my apologies, Line 57 is
String selectedString = (jList.getSelectedValue().toString());
And line 54 is jList.clearSelection();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String selectedString = (jList.getSelectedValue().toString());
```

Looks like this line throws the exception.

You clear selection in the same listener and it in turn calls selection change.

Try to move the value obtaining to be before jList.clearSelection().

Also I would introduce a flag to show the selection change from user's click or from your code which clears selection. Set the flag isMyCode to true (default false) and skip processing if it's true.